# Adding multiple items at once to ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, addition, element

How can I add multiple items at once to an ArrayList?
`ArrayList<Integer> integerArrayList = new ArrayList();` Instead of:
`integerArrayList.add(1)`
`integerArrayList.add(2)`
`integerArrayList.add(3)`
`integerArrayList.add(4)`
...

I would like to: `integerArrayList.add(3, 1, 4, 2);` So that I wont have to type so much. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`Collections.addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-T...-):

```
Collections.addAll(integerArrayList, 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 7):

Is your List fixed? If yes the following should work.

```
List<Integer> integerArrayList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

If the `List` won't need to be added/removed to/from after it's initialized, then use the following:

```
List<Integer> integerArrayList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Otherwise, you should use the following:

```
List<Integer> integerArrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this work for you.

```
    Integer[] array = {1,2,3,4};
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Or you could use a loop to fill the list.

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
   list.add(i);
}
```